# ARMA - GARCH fitting

Tags: arma, garch

I have an ARMA model which has these terms `Constant + AR23 + MA1 + MA3 + MA24`.
The residual of this model has heteroskedasticity (from `ArchTest`) and I am trying to model these using a GARCH. While modelling the residuals through GARCH, I do want to retain the `AR23 + MA1 + MA3 + MA24` terms, although they can have different coefficients after optimization.

Can you please let me know how to do this.

1. Which function (& package) shall I use to model GARCH if I have to retain all the above mentioned parameters?
2. I have tried following in `ugarchspec` function but it is not working.

   2.1 When I use `fixed.pars` argument, I get this error:

   > Error in pars[zf, 1] = unlist(fixed.pars) : NAs are not allowed in
   >   subscripted assignments

   function call as follows:

   ```
   garch_spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
                            mean.model=list(armaOrder = c(1, 4), include.mean = TRUE), 
                            fixed.pars=list(ar23=-0.026922,ma1=-0.497002,ma3=-0.022282, 
                                            ma7=0.015574, ma24=-0.445093))
   ```

   2.2 If don't use `fixed.pars`, then I get a different set of AR and MA terms which I don't want and get all nulls in robust standard errors

   function call:

   ```
   garch_spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
                            mean.model=list(armaOrder = c(1, 4), include.mean=TRUE), 
                            start.pars=list(ar23=-0.026922,ma1=-0.497002,ma3=-0.022282, 
                                            ma7=0.015574,ma24=-0.445093))
   ```

   2.3 In the mean.model, one can mention the order of terms but is there a way to mention the positions of terms, e.g., in my case `AR23 + MA1 + MA3 + MA24`?

   2.4 Is there any other argument of `ugarchspec` that I need to use?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question **1**: using `ugarchspec` and then `ugarchfit` from package `rugarch` is fine.

Answer to question **2**: your problem is that you specify `armaOrder = c(1, 4)` which means an ARMA(1,4) model and then try to restrict terms beyond order (1, 4). You should specify `armaOrder = c(23, 24)` and `fixed.pars = list(ar1=0, ar2=0, ..., ar22=0, ma2=0, ma4=0, ma5=0, ma6=0, ma8=0, ma9=0, ..., ma23=0)` where you should fill in all the terms explicitly in places of elipses (dot-dot-dots).

However, I would think twice before trying to fit this kind of model because the ARMA order seems a bit weird. But perhaps you have a reason behind it...